# How to remove multiple if statements in javascripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have following piece of code.

```
  a = []
   b = []
   c = []
useEffect(() => {

if(isEmpty(a) && isEmpty(b) && isEmpty(c)) {
   data.refetch()
}
if(data.isFetching){
  //do something
}

if(response.isFetching){
  //do something
}

}, [ //Some depedencies ])
```

SO, is there any way through which I can modify this if statements. As I tried with the switch statements but it is not helping over here. So, Any suggestion would e great. Thanks.

Comment: not clear what you are attempting to do. What do mean by some dependencies?

Comment: Just trying to use useEffect , updated the code, its more related to the multiple if statements do we have any other way so that we can refactor them ? or this is the only one.. using multiple if statements as I was able to do this way only

Comment: What's wrong with using those `if` statements? Do the various conditions have any connections to each other?

Comment: You can use if/else if/else statements if appropriate. If you think the chunky code makes it unreadable, create named functions to replace the code inside the if blocks,

Answer (score 3):

You can remove every if of the code in the following way:

```js
a = [];
b = [];
c = [];
conditions = [
[[a,b,c].every((x) => isEmpty(x)), () => data.refetch()],
[data.isFetching, someOtherFunction],
[response.isFetching, anotherFunction]
];
conditions.forEach(cond => cond[0] && cond[1]());
```

I would not recommend this as it makes your code less readable and confusing.

### Explanation:

The function every will test condition for every element of an array and joining with an and:

```js
...
 [a,b,c].every((x) => isEmpty(x)) 
...
```

Then to test every condition you can add them to an array and iterate through them, with a callback for every if you want to create:

```js
conditions = [
[[a,b,c].every((x) => isEmpty(x)), () => data.refetch()],
[data.isFetching, someOtherFunction],
[response.isFetching, anotherFunction]
]
condtions.forEach((cond) => { if(cond[0]) cond[1]() } )
```

Then As suggested by [derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) you could remove the last if with

```js
conditions.forEach(cond => cond[0] && cond[1]());
```

But again, this makes your code more confusing, I would suggest keeping the ifs to make it more clear.

Comment: Hey I got this till  this if(cond[0]) cond[1]()

Comment: Added the missing brackets.

Comment: In that if statement you are evaluating the condition on the first element of every condition and calling the function on the second element.

Comment: That you *can* do something, doesn't mean you *should* do it. Good code is also about maintainability and readability.  And to be honest I personally find that code -- no offense -- terrible. It's hard to read and understand, it's error pone and it's adding too much overhead. Yes, it will remove the `if` statements, as requested, but I don't understand why someone would want to refactor some clean and easy to maintain code to this ...

Comment: And to be consequent, you should also remove the last `if` and refactor `condtions.forEach((cond) => { if(cond[0]) cond[1]() } )` to `conditions.forEach(cond => cond[0] && cond[1]());`

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thanks for the last suggestion too.

Comment: I have just updated the code can u please check it , as it is []

Comment: @ganeshk The code stays the same with your edit. I'll edit the answer with the final form of the code